# How to do multiple bind in KnocckOut Js

Tags: .net, mvvm, data-binding, knockout.js

I am trying to display the paper clip icon  based on condition (Either it should be pop or non pop or both ) which is working fine , but i want to color the paper clip icor based on one more condition  (PopStatus is approved or not ).

i am trying to add both condition in same data bind
can anyone please help me with this ?

html :

```
<td data-bind=" click: $parent.fetchAttachinfo "
                       class="text-center" >
                   

                  <i data-bind="visible: attachmentType=='Non-POP' ,
                   click: function(data,event) {GetPopUpStatus('PopUpApprovalStatus')}, style:{'color':popUpStatus()=='Approved'   ? '#00FF00' : '#ff0000'},i18n: 'service-event.search.result.PopUpApprovalStatus'" class="fa fa-sm fa-paperclip"
                     title="Non-Pop"></i> 
                    <i data-bind="visible: attachmentType=='POP',
                    click: function(data,event) {GetPopUpStatus('PopUpApprovalStatus')}, style:{'color':popUpStatus()=='Approved'   ? '#00FF00' : '#ff0000'},i18n: 'service-event.search.result.PopUpApprovalStatus'" class="fa fa-lg fa-paperclip" title="POP"></i>
                    <i data-bind="visible: attachmentType=='Both' ,
                    click: function(data,event) {GetPopUpStatus('PopUpApprovalStatus')}, style:{'color':popUpStatus()=='Approved'   ? '#00FF00' : '#ff0000'},i18n: 'service-event.search.result.PopUpApprovalStatus'" class="fa fa-lg fa-paperclip"
                        title="POP & Non-Pop"></i>
```

Typescript :

private GetPopUpStatus(popUpStatus: string)
{

```
    if (popUpStatus == "Approved")         
    this.PopUpStatus(popUpStatus);
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure this will answer your questions, but I would look at pulling some of that logic in the view into its own view model.  This is because it cleans up the view and allows you to write tests to check various conditions.

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Test 1',
    status: 'Approved',
    attachmentType: 'POP'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Test 2',
    status: 'Pending',
    attachmentType: 'Non-POP'
  },  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Test 3',
    status: 'Pending',
    attachmentType: 'Both'
  },
];

function AttachmentViewModel(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.id = ko.observable(data.id || null);
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name || '');
  self.popUpStatus = ko.observable(data.status || '');
  self.attachmentType = ko.observable(data.attachmentType || '');
  self.title = ko.computed(function(){
    switch (self.attachmentType()){
      case 'Both': return 'POP & Non-POP';
      default: return self.attachmentType();
      
    }
  });
  self.color = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    switch (self.popUpStatus()) {
      case 'Approved':
        return '#00FF00';
      default:
        return '#ff0000'
    }
  });
};


function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.attachments = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.fetchAttachinfo = function(item) {
    switch (item.popUpStatus()){
      case 'Pending': 
        item.popUpStatus('Approved');
        break;
      default:
        item.popUpStatus('Pending');
        break;
    }
  }
  
  
  self.attachments(data.map(x => new AttachmentViewModel(x)));
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: attachments">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind=" click: $parent.fetchAttachinfo " class="text-center">
        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-paperclip" data-bind="style:{'color':color}, attr:{title: title}"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```